# netsvc (dnscache,wecsvc,tapisvc,nlasvc,cryptsvc) sending stream to address 808:808::3821:ae83:100:20

Tags: networking, ipv6, svchost

i have win 8 installed  on my computer, using pppoe connection with ipv6 disabled. but when i check on "resmon" i saw there is netsvc sending stream to 808:808::3821:ae83:100:20 address. i try to disabled in firewall,netstatagent software or anything, but it just keep sending.

so what is that 808:808::3821:ae83:100:20 anyway ? am i being hacked ? note: i am not opening any program yet at that moment

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a [bogon](http://www.team-cymru.org/Services/Bogons/), an IP address that has not been assigned (or has a special use) and should never appear anywhere on the Internet.

Without knowing more about what the process is that's sending to/from it, it's impossible to say whether you've been "hacked" or not, but certainly something inappropriate is going on.

Comment: i think it control my pc, what i saw, and what i am downloading also files are changed. And what the most danger is it is no a static ip, can always changed, i try to blocked a dozen until now. since that, they change again into ip address looks like this :0.e.0.0.0.0.1.0.3.8.1.a.0.1.0.2.0.0.5.6.0.0.c.6.4.1.7.f.4.1.8.0.ip6.arpa  when i see in resmon. Gezzz. i think internet is not safe anymore for everyone

Comment: Also i think the thing already infect the kernel, no matter what process i start, it can always change the process to send the stream, when i start firefox, it send to other stream same like that. here are the lists:a08:f0f::aca0:1f84:100:e0 <>       
a08:f0f::6833:985:100:e0 <>    
a08:f0f:5f00:5400:2010:a383:100:e0  <>    
a08:1104:7400:6200:2010:a383:100:e0   <>   
a08:1104:7400:6200:6900:6f00:7300:5300  <>     
a08:f0f::6833:985:100:e0      <>
a08:f0f::aca0:1f84:100:e0